# Mongodb - ensureindex for record

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to use ensureindex within records and not for whole collection.

Eg: My database structure is

```
{ "_id" : "com.android.hello", 
    "rating" : [    
        [   {   "user" : "BBFE7F461E10BEE10A92784EFDB",     "value" : "4" } ],  
        [   {   "user" : "BBFE7F461E10BEE10A92784EFDB",     "value" : "4" } ] 
    ] 
}
```

It is a rating system and i don't want the user to rate multiple times on the same application (com.android.hello). If i use ensureindex on the `user` field then user is able to vote only on one application. When i try to vote on a different application altogether (com.android.hi) it says duplicate key.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do this. Uniqueness is only enforced on a per document level. You will need to redesign your schema for the above to work. For example to:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "com.android.hello",
    "rating": {
        "user" : "BBFE7F461E10BEE10A92784EFDB",
        "value" : "4" 
    }
}
```

And then just store multiple...

(I realize you didn't provide the full document though)

Answer (score 0):

```
                      ensureIndex
```

creates indexes , which is applied to whole collection. In case you want only for few records , you may have to keep two collections and apply ensureIndex on one of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

As @Derick said, no however it is possible to make sure they can only vote once atomically:

```
var res=db.votes.update(
    {_id: 'com.android.hello', 'rating.user': {$nin:['BBFE7F461E10BEE10A92784EFDB']}},
    {$push:{rating:{user:'BBFE7F461E10BEE10A92784EFDB',value:4}}},
    {upsert:true}
);
if(res['upserted']||res['n']>0){
    print('voted');
}else
    print('nope');
```

I was a bit concerned that `$push` would not work in `upsert` but I tested this as working.